# save multiple httppostedFile in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i want save 2 gallery in asp.net mvc

i get tow galley with bellow code

```
public ActionResult AddCar(string Name, string TechnicalSpecifications, HttpPostedFileBase[] Gallery, HttpPostedFileBase[] Gall)
```

and save each gallery with bellow code

```
foreach (var item in Gall)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                string urlfile, filename, sub, addstr; int n;
                filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.FileName);
                n = filename.LastIndexOf(".");
                sub = filename.Substring(n);
                addstr = Calender.getdateUrl() + Login.Create10RandomString();
                filename = addstr + sub;
                urlfile = "../../Files/Images/" + filename;
                item.SaveAs(path + filename);

            }
        }
```

but when save this Galleries some images overwrite to another images

for example if i have 6 photo after run save 3 or 2 photo

Comment: Why just don't check wheter file with the same name already exsits (before saving) and change `fileName` when needed?

Comment: when i save file i set name for file that is unique